# Recreating Directory folder of IIS Website

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

[image]The Error pop-up after i accidentally erased 1 shared folder on computer Management, and after i changed the password of the server. Than folder i'm trying to recreate the directory is a website folder, it says "The server service was unable to recreate the share because the directory no longer exists. Please run "net share /delete" to delete the share, or recreate the directory .. But when i try the path is no longer exist.

I try to make new Shared folder on Computer Management Nothings Happened.

Thanks for help in advance

Answer (score 1):

The error is self-explanatory actually.

The folder itself does not exist anymore and thus cannot be shared. Either recreate the folder (check for spelling in case you already did) or delete the share. Keep in mind that the folder is case sensitive.

You may need to close and reopen the window for it to refresh the status of the folder though.

If you can't get it to work, start from the bottom. Remove the share, remove the folder, create the folder, share directly from the folder.

Comment: I Already remove the shared folder then make the new one. **Document** and inside the Documents folder are websites folder. especially the payroll but everytime i access the payroll though internet it can't be reached.

Comment: Your error is talking about Documents\SBProcurements though, its missing that 2nd folder.

Comment: Also, keep in mind, Event log items, will continue to show, even after the problem is resolved. So look if an error comes back to know if there is a problem or not.

Comment: Thanks. "Event log items, will continue to show, even after the problem is resolved." Interesting that Event 2511 resurrects share names long gone from the system.